# Android Back Button deleting activity for good

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, back

I am making a game, and when a level is complete I have a pop-up activity which tells you your score.

When I press the back button I want this instance of the pop-up activity to be deleted for good.

Currently I get the behaviour;

1. Finish level, pop-up appears
2. I press back button to get rid of it
3. Start a new level, finish it and new pop-up appears
4. If I press the back button twice, the new pop-up disappears and the old one re-appears.

I want to delete the old pop-up as soon as it is hidden.

I am using the following code in my pop-up activity;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It clears off the PopupActivity form the Top Activity Stack so that it will not appear again.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent removeIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, PopUpActivity.class);
   removeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(removeIntent);
}
```